# SEM-Path analysis in R

Tags: r, analysis

I run a path analysis in R and the following matrix represents the effect between variables.

```
    M <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    p<-c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    O <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    T <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
    Sales <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0)

sales_path <- rbind(M, p, O, T, Sales)

colnames(sales_path) <- rownames(sales_path)

#innerplot(sales_pls)

sales_blocks <- list(
                c("m1", "m2"),
                #c("pr"),
                c("R1"),
                #c("C1"),
                c("tt1"),
                c("Sales")
)

sales_modes = rep("A", 5)

sales_pls <- plspm(input_file, sales_path, sales_blocks, scheme = "centroid", scaled = FALSE,  modes = sales_modes)
```

I have 2 questions:

1. The weights i receive can i use them to calculate the value of the latent variable e.g. My `M` variable has the manifest variables is there a formula to calculate its value?
2. The main purpose i run path analysis is to predict the sales. Is that possible by using the `estimations(beta)` for each latent variable?

Comment: What code are you using to run the analysis? I don't know the answer to your question, but that might help other people to answer your questions.

Comment: Indeed, much more information with sample data and the code you're using to actually construct/test the model would be necessary for us to give you any kind of useful feedback on your problem.  In general, if your question is whether you can estimate an SEM model in R the answer is yes, using a variety of techniques and packages.

Comment: I run the path analysis model in order to find the effects between the variables but i want to know if i am able to calculate the value of the latent variable and then if i can predict Sales using the betas from the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to know if i am able to calculate the value of the latent
>   variable

Yes. Its actually very easy. Your latent variable scores can be obtained by running `sales_pls$scores`. You can also run `summary(sales_pls)`. For easier interpretation you may wish to have the latent variables expressed in the same scale as the indicators (manifest variables). This can be accomplished by normalizing the outer weights in each block of indicators so that the weights are expressed as proportions. However, in order to apply this normalization all the outer weights must be positive.
You can apply the function `rescale()` to the object `sales_pls` and get scores expressed in the original scale of the manifest variables. Once you get the rescaled scores you can use `summary()` to verify that the obtained results make sense (i.e. scores expressed in original scale of indicators):

```
# rescaling scores
rescaled_sales_pls = rescale(sales_pls)
# summary
summary(rescaled_sales_pls)
```

(again you can also run `rescaled_sales_pls`)

> if i can predict Sales using the betas from the output

Theoretically I guess you could, but I'm not really sure why you would want to. The utility of path analysis here is to decompose the sources of a correlation between an independent variable and a dependent variable of a multiple regression model.

Comment: @JamesMarshall - if this is answers your question please click the check mark to next to the answer so that others will know the question is closed. Thanks.